# Multiple indices under a single name in kibana is possible?

Tags: indexing, customization, kibana, indices

I want multiple indices to be under one name.. How can i do that in kibana... as shown in this picture..so that the logs ( app,server,db) of the server1 and the logs of server 2 under it. How can we customize to make multiple indices under one name. { https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3eV8.png }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood perfectly but you can use an index pattern in kibana like "server*"

Or an other possibility would be to add alias to your indices, they would be accessible with the same index name in kibana

Comment: Actually in kibana i'm able to use one index at a time.... but i want a seperate view like that in that pic... for suppose there are 2 servers... under server 1 there are db,windows,server logs...like that in server 2 also... i want overview of these things in kibana dashboard to present... but in kibana im able to use only one index at a time..i.e., im accesing only db logs at a time..windows logs at a time... i want whole overview that what are the logs under server 1 and server2... if i click db logs under server1 ..it must show those logs...

Comment: And the Alias option can't work? if u make a "log" alias to all of your index (db2, web1, androidLog.....) it will all be shown in one kibana index.